# Weird permissions behaviour (Sp2013 using Managed Metadata)

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

We have a SharePoint 2013 Enterprise on-prem with a bunch of managed metadata for tagging and for navigation.

We have a small set of contractors that aren't allowed to do anything on the main site, except they can add Announcements.

I have set unique permissions on the Announcements list and given the contractor group Contribute permissions. The can read the Announcements list and nothing else (hooray), but when they try to ADD to the list the get an Access Request screen (boo!). When they follow through with the Access Request, I get a request for "Edit" permissions on the list. I don't want them to add/edit/delete the list, just add and edit items.

When I do "check permissions", the user in question definitely has Contribute.

Is this something to do with MM and hidden lists? The Announcements list in question does have several MM fields.

Any suggestions would be most welcome,
Thank you,